# How to create precise platformer movement using MatterJS?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm using MatterJS to create a simple tile-based platformer, but running into issues getting both gravity and movement to work together.

My goal is to have it so the player is only partially physics driven, where they are affected by gravity, collide with walls, and push other physics objects around, but at the same time have "snappy," left/right movement, where the instant the direction isn't being held, the player stops moving in that direction.

Things I've tried and the results:

- Using `Matter.Body.setVelocity()` resulted in the object moving long after I released the button.
- Using `Matter.Body.setVelocity()` and then trying to clear the velocity in `afterUpdate` means gravity stops being applied correctly.
- Using `Matter.Body.translate()` for L/R movement resulted in almost exactly what I wanted, except the player would always lightly clip into walls, causing them to get stuck  instead of sliding down.
- Using `Matter.Body.applyForce()` in `beforeUpdate()` to apply the direction vector resulted in the object still moving after I released the button, and moving at different speeds depending on if it was on the ground or not.
- Using `Matter.Body.applyForce()` in `beforeUpdate()` and attempting to apply an equal but opposite force in `afterUpdate()` resulted in some really strange behavior.

Any idea how I would go about implementing this?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of your code? Thanks.

Comment: Got nothing constructive for you except some anecdotes. I worked on a billiards prototype using matter.js and had the same kinds of issues. I would still recommend the library, but it requires a deeper dive if doing anything which isn't already covered in their demos. Some revelations were around managing the animator (toggling it at specific times) and trying to accurately line-up bitmap graphics to physics objects (circle bitmaps to circle physics objects), etc. The last mystery I recall was fighting the physics engine when attempting to allow the user control like drag-drop of an object.

Comment: You might have better luck on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with @Kalnode. In most cases, if you're not using MJS as it is out of the box, it's going to be a serious struggle to implement what you want. `Body.set` overrides the physics engine and is difficult to control in a natural way. You may want to implement the simple movement and collision on your own. But it's hard to say without actual code to work with--it may be that this is one of the cases where a couple of simple override tricks lets you implement what you want.

Comment: Setting friction (and maybe frictionAir) very high might be one way to implement "dead stop" behavior when the key stops being pressed. It'll take more force to move the player, but they will be less likely to coast when the force isn't being applied. Maybe adjusting the mass could help too.

Comment: Does anyone know of a physics library that might be better for my use case then? All I really care about is gravity and resolving collisions